# How to calculate distance from lat/long point to each habitat category in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity, land-cover

I am very new to QGIS and am struggling so hopefully someone will be able to help me with what I assume is a relatively simple task.

I have a number of vector layers of land cover from the land cover 2007 dataset, available from edina digimap. (categories: agriculture, alternative, builtup, freshwater, grassland, intertidal, offshore marine). I also have a vector layer of points (lat/long). I basically need to calculate the distances (km) from each point to each habitat category, and end up with a table with column names (lat, long, dist to hab A, dist to hab B, dist to hab C....etc.).

I've been trying to convert the landcover shapefiles to rasters as this seems to be the first step (from looking online), and have thus far been unsuccessful - I think because I'm not sure what values to use to define extent and the like. Having trawled online (similar) questions I then tried to convert to rasters in R (more familiar with this environment) and couldnt load the files in - fell at the first hurdle!

Hoping someone can help me out!

Comment: The NNJoin plugin worked perfectly - thanks very much for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [NNJoin](http://arken.nmbu.no/~havatv/gis/qgisplugins/NNJoin/) plugin to complete this task. See [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html) for steps on installing a plugin if you're not sure.

Comment: You should add those steps to your answer keeping the link as reference.